# Android openCSV, file appearing - but won't write anything

Tags: java, android, io, opencsv

```
public void exportToCSV() throws IOException {

    File pathfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath()
            + File.separator
            + "csvData");
    if (!pathfile.isDirectory()) {
        pathfile.mkdir();
    }

    File file = new File(pathfile,
                File.separator + "csvDataFile.csv");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            if (csvThreadRunning) {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    try {

                        String s1 = String.valueOf(globalData
                                .getLatestGraphData1()) + "pin39"; // array
                                                                    // of
                                                                    // your
                                                                    // values
                        writer.writeNext(s1);
                        s1 = String.valueOf(globalData
                                .getLatestGraphData2()) + "pin40";
                        writer.writeNext(s1);
                        s1 = String.valueOf(globalData
                                .getLatestGraphData3()) + "pin41";
                        writer.writeNext(s1);
                        s1 = String.valueOf(globalData
                                .getLatestGraphData4()) + "pin42";
                        writer.writeNext(s1);
                        s1 = String.valueOf(globalData
                                .getLatestGraphData5()) + "pin43";
                        writer.writeNext(s1);
                        writer.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();

}
```

Csv file appears in the correct path but no data is written to it?

Comment: also I put a log into the thread and it is indeed running the thread.

Comment: Are you sure `csvThreadRunning` is true? Are you getting any Exceptions in the `try-catch`?

Comment: Yes, csvThreadRunning is true because it is set true by a boolean in a compoundbutton (togglebutton) immediately before the method above is called.

Comment: and no I am not getting an exception; the program actually wrote once and stopped writing after the first write. Is it because the writer.close is not reopening the writer after the first thread run?

Comment: I was correct; from my last statement re-writing the code so that the writer didn't close fixed it.

Comment: Only problem now is how can I limit it from writing massive amounts of data? Put a sleep in the thread?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I closed the `writer` too early; causing the csv file to write one column and then stop.

Solution was to move the `writer.close();` outside of the run loop.